# Face verification of given bounding box

Tags: python, face-detection, face-recognition

I am working on face recognition demo using python library of face_recognition.

```
 # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
```

the above code, with the best of my understanding detect the faces in given frame of different sizes. What if I want to draw a bounding box, and if there is a face on that bounding box then only that face should be used for further processing. I don't my CPU to detect faces all over the frame of different size, but only from area of interest with fix size.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image, crop it to only the bounding box, then run face recognition on that newly cropped image.

```
# Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
#crop image based on some bounding box
rgb_cropped = rgb_small_frame[boundy1:boundy2,boundx1,boundx2]

# Only process every other frame of video to save time
# Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_cropped)
```

Comment: Thank you jeff, but it still slide of different size bounding boxes on that crop image. I want to restrict only particular size of the face.

Comment: That module will find ALL faces in an image,  I think you'll have to implement some post-processing to eliminate unwanted features based on size

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try deepface? It applies face recognition in real time with a single line of code.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/my_db")
```

Here, you should store the facial images data base in C:/my_db folder.